# How do I include Typed.js in an Aurelia project

Tags: javascript, aurelia, typed.js

I've installed it using `npm`. I've added it to my dependencies in `aurelia.json`:

```
"dependencies": [
  // ...
  {
    "name": "typed",
    "path": "../node_modules/typed.js/src"
  }
]
```

And I've imported it into my file like so:

```
import Typed from 'typed';
```

Yet when I try to call it `var typed = new Typed(...);` I get a `Typed is not defined` exception. [According to their docs](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/#setup) things should be pretty simple so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you programming in TypeScript or ES?

Comment: @AshleyGrant ES

Answer (score 1):

You got some errors in your `aurelia.json` declaration. The `dist` of **typed.js** is located in `lib` and not in `src` and you sould define the main file. Try the following:

```
"dependencies": [
  // ...
  {
    "name": "typed",
    "path": "../node_modules/typed.js/lib",
    "main": "typed"
  }
```